# React - Navigating between urls without page loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am building a website using react. I have a url http://0.0.0.0:9000/courseware/course/6/content/programming/issues/lab/1 which shows a list of issues belonging to a lab of id 1.

When I click on an issue (eg, 22), I want the url to become http://0.0.0.0:9000/courseware/course/6/content/programming/issue/22.

I tried doing this

```
this.props.history.push({
     pathname: "issue/" + this.state.issue.id
})
```

but then the url would become /programming/issues/lab/1/issue/22

I tried doing this

```
const history = useHistory();
history.goBack();
this.props.history.push({
     pathname: "issue/" + this.state.issue.id
})
```

but there is a react hook error

Then I tried doing

```
this.props.history.goBack();
this.props.history.push({
     pathname: "issue/" + this.state.issue.id
})
```

but this is navigating the page and the below push function doesn't work.

First, Am I dealing with the urls in right way? If yes, then How do I solve this problem?

I am assuming I have to use history to navigate between urls without actually reloading the page.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can't you use react-router-dom? It's much easier

Comment: Did you try with relative pathnames ? `../../../issue/this.state.issue.id`

Comment: Please share a more complete and comprehensive code example for what you are trying to do. This may, or may not, be an XY problem, meaning you think this `history.push` is the solution but it isn't working so you are asking how to make it work. If we've better context for what the code is doing, where it is, and what you are trying to do we may be able to suggest an optimal or alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I suggest to address the issue using this kind of relative pathname:
`"../../../issue/this.state.issue.id"`.
This way you are able to navigate with `react-router` to the path you want relatively to the current path.
You were on the right track by using the relative path:

```
this.props.history.push({
     pathname: "issue/" + this.state.issue.id
})
```

You had just to tell it to go 3 steps back.

Comment: Questions asking for clarification should be made as comments. Since you already did that this should probably be proposed as an answer with brief explanation of the issue it resolves.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can achieve this is by adding `/` before the url and appending the id to the whole url. This way react router will know that you're inserting a absolute url path not the relative one.

```
this.props.history.push({
     pathname: `/courseware/course/${some-id}/content/programming/issue/${this.state.issue.id}`
})
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution other than aboslute path. Thank you nevertheless :)

Answer (score 1):

Use react-router-dom it's much easier.
Firstly,
`npm i -D react-router-dom`

`Basic Usage`

`index.js:`

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Blogs from "./pages/Blogs";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import NoPage from "./pages/NoPage";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
          <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

### Example Explained

We wrap our content first with `<BrowserRouter>`.

Then we define our `<Routes>`. An application can have multiple `<Routes>`. Our basic example only uses one.

`<Route>`s can be nested. The first `<Route>` has a path of / and renders the Layout component.

The nested `<Route>`s inherit and add to the parent route. So the blogs path is combined with the parent and becomes /blogs.

The Home component route does not have a path but has an index attribute. That specifies this route as the default route for the parent route, which is /.

Setting the path to * will act as a catch-all for any undefined URLs. This is great for a 404 error page.

### Pages / Components

The Layout component has  and  elements.

The `<Outlet>` renders the current route selected.

`<Link>` is used to set the URL and keep track of browsing history.

Anytime we link to an internal path, we will use `<Link>` instead of `<a href="">`.

The "layout route" is a shared component that inserts common content on all pages, such as a navigation menu.

`Layout.js:`

```js
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/blogs">Blogs</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
};

export default Layout;
```